# Is it possible to parse non-trivial C enums with pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a preprocessed C file and I need to enumerate the members of one of the enums inside it. `pyparsing` ships with a simple example for that (`examples/cpp_enum_parser.py`), but it only works when enum values are positive integers. In real life a value may be negative, hex, or a complex expression.

I don't need structured values, just the names.

```
enum hello {
    minusone=-1,
    par1 = ((0,5)),
    par2 = sizeof("a\\")bc};,"),
    par3 = (')')
};
```

When parsing the value, the parser should skip everything until `[('",}]` and handle these chars. For that Regex or SkipTo may be useful. For strings and chars - QuotedString. For nested parentheses - Forward (`examples/fourFn.py`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

altered the original example. I don't know why they removed `enum.ignore(cppStyleComment)` from the original script. Put it back.

```
from pyparsing import *
# sample string with enums and other stuff
sample = '''
    stuff before
    enum hello {
        Zero,
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Five=5,
        Six,
        Ten=10,
        minusone=-1,
        par1 = ((0,5)),
        par2 = sizeof("a\\")bc};,"),
        par3 = (')')
        };
    in the middle
    enum
        {
        alpha,
        beta,
        gamma = 10 ,
        zeta = 50
        };
    at the end
    '''

# syntax we don't want to see in the final parse tree
LBRACE,RBRACE,EQ,COMMA = map(Suppress,"{}=,")


lpar  = Literal( "(" )
rpar  = Literal( ")" )
anything_topl = Regex(r"[^'\"(,}]+")
anything      = Regex(r"[^'\"()]+")

expr = Forward()
pths_or_str = quotedString | lpar + expr + rpar
expr <<     ZeroOrMore( pths_or_str | anything )
expr_topl = ZeroOrMore( pths_or_str | anything_topl )

_enum = Suppress('enum')
identifier = Word(alphas,alphanums+'_')
expr_topl_text = originalTextFor(expr_topl)
enumValue = Group(identifier('name') + Optional(EQ + expr_topl_text('value')))
enumList = Group(ZeroOrMore(enumValue + COMMA) + Optional(enumValue) )
enum = _enum + Optional(identifier('enum')) + LBRACE + enumList('names') + RBRACE
enum.ignore(cppStyleComment)

# find instances of enums ignoring other syntax
for item,start,stop in enum.scanString(sample):
    for entry in item.names:
        print('%s %s = %s' % (item.enum,entry.name, entry.value))
```

result:

```
$ python examples/cpp_enum_parser.py
hello Zero =
hello One =
hello Two =
hello Three =
hello Five = 5
hello Six =
hello Ten = 10
hello minusone = -1
hello par1 = ((0,5))
hello par2 = sizeof("a\")bc};,")
hello par3 = (')')
 alpha =
 beta =
 gamma = 10
 zeta = 50
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to special case the terms that might contain a comma or right brace that doesn't mark end of the enum value.

```
from pyparsing import *

sample = r"""
enum hello {
    minusone=-1,
    par1 = ((0,5)),
    par2 = sizeof("a\")bc};,"),
    par3 = (')')
};
"""

ENUM = Keyword("enum")
LBRACE,RBRACE,COMMA,EQ = map(Suppress, "{},=")
identifier = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_")
identifier.setName("identifier")#.setDebug()

funcCall = identifier + nestedExpr()

enum_value = nestedExpr() | quotedString | funcCall | SkipTo(COMMA | RBRACE)

enum_decl = (ENUM + Optional(identifier, '')("ident") + LBRACE + 
    OneOrMore(identifier + Optional(EQ + enum_value).suppress() + Optional(COMMA))("names") +
    RBRACE
    )

for enum in enum_decl.searchString(sample):
    print enum.ident, ','.join(enum.names)
```

prints

```
hello minusone,par1,par2,par3
```

Comment: Haven't noticed nestedExpr. Thanks